# Set <select> value to a non-existent option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a select with options. I need to set the default of the dropdown to a value that is not in the dropdown list. The user can then leave it the same or select a value from the options in the select.

How can this be achieved?

**Edit:**
This is the scenario: I have a set of data that is normalized. This is fed into the select (as options). After rendering, a value is selected by default. However, sometimes, this value (that has to be selected) might not be in the options - so a good UX would be to still have this shown as the selected option, even if it is not in the normalized data. The user can leave it be or select a "correct" option.

Comment: `I need to set the default of the dropdown to a value that is not in the dropdown list` this is not possible, although to be honest the rest of your question doesn't make much sense. What exactly are you trying to achieve, as I can guarantee you there will be a better way.

Comment: Why should not be in the select if it is selected? Probably you want that one selected by default?

Comment: Do you mean to add an option to the dropdown list or something along these lines?

Comment: I am not sure I understand, but if you want a default option it is still an option so it must be part of the select. If this is a default you want you need to add this <option selected="selected">default option</option>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean for a placeholder similar to text inputs.  The only way I know of to do this is to make the selected option disabled; however, it **must** still be an option in the markup.  e.g.

```html
<select>
    <option disabled="" selected="" value="">Select one of the Options Below</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

You may be better served by making your own javascript powered one.